# Do sqlite commands via bash

Tags: bash, sqlite, sh

I don't want to run these commands manually. How can I automate that in bash script?

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/pve-cluster/config.db
sqlite> select * from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
sqlite> delete from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
sqlite> select * from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
sqlite> .quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [heredocs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/pve-cluster/config.db <<EOF
select * from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
delete from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
select * from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

`sqlite3 /path/to/file.db "$command"`

From your command prompt.

For example:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/pve-cluster/config.db "select * from tree where name = 'corosync.conf';"
```